# SQL IO Latency on VSphere 5.5 affected by memory allocation?

Tags: sql, performance, latency, vsphere

What is the relationship between memory and physical disk latency on a SQL 2012 server running on VSphere 5.5?  Does reducing memory to the point where PLE counter values go below 100 cause IO latency which shows as increased physical disk seconds/read and seconds/write values? If so, what is the recommendation regarding memory as it relates to desired IO performance?

On our SQL 2012 server residing on Windows 2012 R2 I lowered the amount of memory available to the OS from 96Gb to 64Gb due to great performance and high daytime PLE counter values (evening PLE counter values were low, but performance was not an issue during this timeframe). I changed SQL 'max server memory (Mb)' from 92Gb to 60Gb.  The result was no change during the daytime window (as expected), and an unexpected significant physical disk latency (seconds/read and seconds/write) during evening maintenance.  When increasing memory back to the original 96Gb for the OS and 92Gb for SQL, performance improved and physical disk latency reduced to normal.

I have observed this correlation between memory and physical disk latency; however I am not ready to say reducing memory caused physical disk latency as I have not found anything online confirming this.

Has anyone else observed an increase in physical disk latency when reducing memory?

Configuration:
VSphere 5.5
Windows 2012 R2 x64
SQL 2012
CPU 4socket 2core each for total of 8 core
Database 1.6tb, split across 3 drives plus a drive for logs

Comment: The simple answer is yes. If your PLE values are that low then SQL Server will have to retrieve the data from disk frequently. What maintenance was being run? CheckDB?

Comment: I was running both DBCC CHECKDB and UPDATE STATISTICS WITH FULLSCAN.

I understand this will cause more data to be retrieved from disk, but why would latency (reads/second) increase?  I thought latency would remain the same unless something else happened like an overflow causing re-execution of commands.

Comment: Are you running it during an approved maintenance window? If the performance is unacceptable even for a maintenance window then you need to look at altering when you perform maintenance or look into alternatives. For instance you could take a backup and restore to another server that isn't in production and run CheckDB on it.

Comment: Yes.  It is an approved (the only) maintenance window.  Good idea to move CHECKDB to another server - not possible for us.